# Some syntax I don't know in zlib (C/C++) ZEXTERN ZEXPORT OF ... compile error

Tags: c++, c, syntax, zlib

I am trying to compile zlib 1.2.11 to replace an old version we use with vxWorks 6.8, and I run into compile issues.

Checking the code, I don't know the syntax which has been used there:

```cpp
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzwrite OF((gzFile file, voidpc buf, unsigned len));
```

What's `ZEXTERN`, `ZEXPORT`, and `OF()`?

Also:

```cpp
int ZEXPORT gzgetc(file)
    gzFile file;
{
    unsigned char c;
    return gzread(file, &c, 1) == 1 ? c : -1;
}
```

It looks like an hybrid between C and C++.

I couldn't fine much documentation.

Comment: They are probably preprocessor macros. Search the code base for their definitions.

Comment: The implementation of `gzgetc()` is written in K&R style.  Otherwise, the only thing at all strange about it is the `ZEXPORT`, which will be the same macro as is used in the `gzwrite` declaration presented previously.

Comment: The `OF` macro expands to `()` if the compiler does not recognize prototype notation — and to the argument list in the inner parentheses (including those inner parentheses) if the compiler does recognize prototypes.  Such coding is seldom needed these days, but twenty or more years ago, was a necessary exercise for portability to pre-standard C compilers.

Comment: The `int ZEXPORT gzgetc(file) gzFile file;` in the *Also* is really old, pre ANSI C. In the old days you (optionally) specified the variable name and then specified the type later. For a bunch of reasons this style trended toward chaos, so it was replaced by the `int ZEXPORT gzgetc(gzFile  file)` style you see today.

Answer (score 4):

`ZEXTERN`, `ZEXPORT`, and `OF()` are preprocessor macros defined in zlib's `zconf.h` header file:

```c
#if defined(WINDOWS) || defined(WIN32)
   /* If building or using zlib as a DLL, define ZLIB_DLL.
    * This is not mandatory, but it offers a little performance increase.
    */
#  ifdef ZLIB_DLL
#    if defined(WIN32) && (!defined(__BORLANDC__) || (__BORLANDC__ >= 0x500))
#      ifdef ZLIB_INTERNAL
#        define ZEXTERN extern __declspec(dllexport)
#      else
#        define ZEXTERN extern __declspec(dllimport)
#      endif
#    endif
#  endif  /* ZLIB_DLL */
   /* If building or using zlib with the WINAPI/WINAPIV calling convention,
    * define ZLIB_WINAPI.
    * Caution: the standard ZLIB1.DLL is NOT compiled using ZLIB_WINAPI.
    */
#  ifdef ZLIB_WINAPI
#    ifdef FAR
#      undef FAR
#    endif
#    include <windows.h>
     /* No need for _export, use ZLIB.DEF instead. */
     /* For complete Windows compatibility, use WINAPI, not __stdcall. */
#    define ZEXPORT WINAPI
#    ifdef WIN32
#      define ZEXPORTVA WINAPIV
#    else
#      define ZEXPORTVA FAR CDECL
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#if defined (__BEOS__)
#  ifdef ZLIB_DLL
#    ifdef ZLIB_INTERNAL
#      define ZEXPORT   __declspec(dllexport)
#      define ZEXPORTVA __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#      define ZEXPORT   __declspec(dllimport)
#      define ZEXPORTVA __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#ifndef ZEXTERN
#  define ZEXTERN extern
#endif
#ifndef ZEXPORT
#  define ZEXPORT
#endif
#ifndef ZEXPORTVA
#  define ZEXPORTVA
#endif

...

#ifndef OF /* function prototypes */
#  ifdef STDC
#    define OF(args)  args
#  else
#    define OF(args)  ()
#  endif
#endif
```

In a nutshell:

When zlib is compiled/linked-to as a DLL, `ZEXTERN` maps to `extern __declspec(dllexport)` or `extern __declspec(dllimport)` on Windows, and to `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` on BEOS.  For all other build configurations, it maps to `extern` instead.

`ZEXPORT` maps to `WINAPI` (aka `__stdcall`) on Windows, otherwise it maps to nothing (ie, the compiler's default calling convention, which is usually `__cdecl`).

`OF()` emits the specified parameter list under standard C/C++, otherwise it hides the list.

So, for example, when compiling zlib as a DLL for Windows, this declaration:

```c
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzwrite OF((gzFile file, voidpc buf, unsigned len));
```

is seen by the compiler as this code:

```c
extern __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall gzwrite (gzFile file, voidpc buf, unsigned len);
```

Under certain compilers, it could end up being as simple as this instead:

```c
extern int gzwrite ();
```